# Google play keeps asking me to remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, but my merged manifest does not have it

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-package-managers

I get "Update Rejected" in Google Play console, stating that I need either remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission or provide policy declaration for it.

The thing is, I **do not have** this permissions nor in main, nor in **merged** AndroidManifest.xml!

I specifically removed years ago it with `tools:node="remove"`.

I do, however use package manager to retrieve the package info of one app - my other game, for that I have a `queries` entry in AndroidManifest.xml like this:

```
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.package.of.my.other.game" />
    </queries>
```

Can I be getting this scary REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES update rejection because of the queries tag?

If so, is there any other way to check if my other app is installed? (both apps are even signed with the same key if it matters).

I also had this for ages now, but suddenly *after an app play store icon update (no new apk uploads)* Google Play rejected the update with this weird reasoning.

Comment: same issue here...I think there is an issue in google play

Comment: Good to know I'm not the only one. I sent the appeal form, but I don't expect much to come from it knowing how people usually have problems getting past bot replies on google play issues.

Answer (score 1):

We are encountering the same issue and just sent an appeal to Google with this URL in our appeal. Let's hope they resolved. Like others we explicitly excluded this permission using the node="remove". It looks like they are just doing a string comparison on the Manifest file instead of a more in depth analysis to see if it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what's going on with Google Play nowadays, but it **rejected my appeal** but **approved my next update** with only ui changes and thanked me for addressing the issue.

The issue which wasn't there in the first place.

Will the problem return in the future app version uploads? We do not know.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using open_file package

change to better_open_file package

[better open file](https://pub.dev/packages/better_open_file)

Comment: Thanks I'm not using flatter, and even if that was the case, I believe I would still had the permission requested in the merged manifest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).