# Rejected from Google Play REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

my app got rejected from Google Play Store. The feedback from Google play is because of `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission?
My app doesn't have that permission, I think it might be from the plugin that I use.
In manifest, I also added this:

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
tools:node="remove"/>
```

but still got rejected.
How to fix this issue? I need to upload the app asap.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [REQUEST\_INSTALL\_PACKAGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809824/request-install-packages)

Comment: You have to upload new app in all your active testing tracks like internal testing, beta , etc

Answer (score 0):

You can check all permission used in your app at google play console.
[image]

If your app doesn't have **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** you must contact Google via email or phone and request again.

Comment: Maybe you already have a previous Internal Testing version that uses this permission. But your current version does not. And you need to contact via email to resolve. I have had this case before. Hope can help you