# Google Play Console - cannot submit updates, because in Internal Testing there is a bundle requesting sensitive permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: testing, installation, request, bundle, internals

In Google Play Console I created an Internal Testing a few months ago. I want to start Closed Testing with a newer version (another bundle) but I cannot do this because in the old bundle in the Internal Testing there is a sensitive permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES requested.

I have found a related question with a solution for my problem ([REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73809824/request-install-packages?newreg=0ae72473a6af499981ba1c1f3f406c00)).

I tried to create another Internal Testing with “good” bundle, in order to “disable” the older release with the “bad” bundle, but I cannot find a way to create a second release for Internal Testing.